# Invalid decimal on values less than zero e.g. ",5"

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import

I am trying to import a file from the enhanced SFTP location into one of my data extensions. I have a decimal column in my DE with the length of (8,2). When I import the file I get the error

> InvalidDecimal

on a row that contains the decimal with a value of `,5`. I'd like to know why this value is not accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas are not accepted with Decimal Data type.

Reference :

- [Data Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5)

Comment: You are right! Thank you. I will try to remove the comma character from my exported file and try with dots and see if it works. Will come back to you regarding this.